# What are the advantages of using metaclasses in django-like form implementations?

Tags: python, django, oop, class, metaclass

First a little background ... I was going over the Django source code for forms to understand the implementation of forms in Django (and to learn some Python along the way). Django implements forms using a  DeclaredMetaFields *MetaClass*.

Here is a very crude class diagram of a Django-like form implementation ([link](https://gist.github.com/893653) to sample code in gist).

[image: Django-form-like implementation of ContactForm - Class Diagram]

And here is an instance diagram.

[image: Django-form-like implementation of ContactForm - Instance Diagram]

Here is a *very crude* implementation the same class without resorting to meta-classes ([link](https://gist.github.com/893658) to sample code in gist).

[image: A simple and crude implementation of ContactForm]

I understand the metaclass concepts etc. and understand how the Django code works. Now for the questions.

1. Other than the obvious benefits such as syntactical elegance etc. are there any other benefits for the meta-class implementation?
2. Is the meta-class like implementation possible without resorting to an intermediate object like BoundField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well syntactical benefits matters a lot. After all even classes in OOP languages is just a syntactical benefit of the language.

In your example of very crude implementation of meta-class-less form implementation you describe fields in Dict. Well you might have overlooked that it is actually [SortedDict](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SortedDict#SortedDict), because ordering of fields matters. So I'll need to define `fields_order` list as well.

Next big thing is [ModelForm](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#module-django.forms.models). Meta-class approach allows to simply say which Model do I use and which fields in `Meta` attribute and it automatically creates and maps fields to model. Without Metaclass approach I would probably have to use something like `CreateFieldsFromModel` and `MapFieldsToModel`. Or you might do that for me in `__init__` method. But wait, `__init__` method is already complex enough with lots of arguments like `data`, `initial`, `files`, and more.

```
class MyForm(Form):
    fields = {
        'one': ...
        ...
    }
    fields_order = [...]
    model_fields = ???

Class MyForm2(MyForm):
    fields = MyForm.fields + {...}

# ... hey this API sucks! I think I'll go with another framework.
```

And there are many more things which can be configured in forms and everything is documented.

So for me, because of huge configuration logic, it looks like `Form` just asks to be implemented through definition-object and factory-logic. And here comes python with its metaclasses to hide the factory from the user. And it is cool because it makes beginners to think less.

And well yea its syntactical sugar all around and its all about making easy to use API.

And yes it is possible not to use Metaclasses/BoundField or whatever else. In the end it is possible to write all implementation of forms in one function and have all definition in one big dict (or xml?) But will that be easy to use, easy to understand, easy to extend?

Comment: For me the most important point you made is  ...  "Form just asks to be implemented through definition-object and factory-logic. And here comes python with its metaclasses to hide the factory from the user."


I guess I was wondering if the same level of API abstraction could be accomplished without metaclasses, but metaclasses are cleaner and hide a lot of details from the end user (and since they're tucked away in the source code, user really doesn't have to bother too much about the details). Thanks for taking the time to answer the question.